# Community plattform to translate free or open source software

Tags: translation

In the past I found web communities where you can upload language files of your own (free / open source) software. And the community will translate it for you and you can monitor the progress, etc.

But currently I can not find a community like this. I only find plattforms where you have to pay for that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a number of communities springing up around OpenTranslators, which seems more like matchmaking than anything else. http://opentranslators.org/

However, I've had experience with the locally hosted version of Zanata (http://zanata.org/) which can run on a server for invited translators, or failing that there's usually people around their local setup that actually will offer translation support (https://translate.zanata.org/) With that you can supply your text and get feedback, and with RedHat support it should remain free and open for a good long time.